# unique synthesised name

Tags: c++, compiler-theory

I would like to generate various data types in C++ with unique deterministic names. For example:

```
struct struct_int_double { int mem0; double mem1; };
```

At present my compiler synthesises names using a counter, which means the names don't agree when compiling the same data type in distinct translation units.

Here's what won't work:

1. Using the ABI mangled_name function. Because it depends already on structs having unique names. Might work in C++11 compliant ABI by pretending struct is anonymous?
2. Templates eg struct2 because templates don't work with recursive types.
3. A complete mangling. Because it gives names which are way too long (hundreds of characters!)

Apart from a global registry (YUK!) the only thing I can think of is to first create a unique long mangled name, and then use a digest or hash function to shorten it (and hope there are no clashes).

Actual problem: to generate libraries which can be called where the types are anonymous, eg tuples, sum types, function types.

Any other ideas?

EDIT: Addition description of recursive type problem. Consider defining a linked list like this:

```
template<class T>
typedef pair<list<T>*, T> list;
```

This is actually what is required. It doesn't work for two reasons: first, you can't template a typedef. [NO, you can NOT use a template class with a typedef in it, it doesn't work] Second, you can't pass in list* as an argument because it isn't defined yet. In C without polymorphism you can do it:

```
struct list_int { struct list_int *next; int value; };
```

There are several work arounds. For this *particular* problem you can use a variant of the Barton-Nackman trick, but it doesn't generalise.

There is a general workaround, first shown me by Gabrielle des Rois, using a template with open recursion, and then a partial specialisation to close it. But this is extremely difficult to generate and would probably be unreadable even if I could figure out how to do it.

There's another problem doing variants properly too, but that's not directly related (it's just worse because of the stupid restriction against declaring unions with constructable types).

Therefore, my compiler simply uses ordinary C types. It has to handle polymorphism anyhow: one of the reasons for writing it was to bypass the problems of C++ type system including templates. This then leads to the naming problem.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::tuple`? (Or `std::tr1::tuple`) What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: What's wrong with `.get<N>()` instead of `.memN`?

Comment: @Billy: There's no such thing as std::tuple (in C++98 anyhow). If C++11 has this and it's a template it won't work (templates can't handle recursive types), and I would be reluctant to use it since my current g++ on OSX doesn't have much C++11 support (unfortunate).

Comment: @Johannes: why would I use .get<N>()? The data types aren't templates, why make them templates just for this notation?

Comment: @Yttrill: std::tuple is exactly what you need. You can use boost::tuple until you get a C++0x compiler.

Comment: @Yttrill: what do you mean by recursive types?

Comment: See above edit for an example of recursive types. basically any type which refers to itself directly or indirectly is a recursive type. All trees and lists are recursive types.

Comment: Or look at the discussion in boot::variants docs (same example: linked list).

Comment: @Yttrill, I can't get your question. How do you want to generate structures - by an external tool (your own translator to C?), or by the inbuilt C++ capabilities? If the problem is name mangling, how do they avoid it in existing compilers, or why don't they have it? Is it all because of the recursive types? Could you clarify?

Comment: @Yttrill: Re: Your edit. Those are two completely different implementation patterns. You can just as easily define a list template in the second manner: `template<class T> struct list{ list *next; T value; };`

Comment: @7vies: I am already generating the structures, the problem is naming them in a deterministic way. If I could use template just for the name, I could still use my generated structures for the definitions, just make them specialisations of the template, which has no definition and serves only to supply the name.

Comment: @Steve M: read comment on answer below. Of course I can define a list as you say, but where would the name "list" come from? The problem is for anonymous types: ones made without a name. Then I have to synthesise a name from the structure of the type.

Comment: `[NO, you can NOT use a template class with a typedef in it, it doesn't work]` <-- What doesn't work about it? `std::vector` sure as hell is a template, and it has tons of typedefs... More to the point, you say that you're generating code -- why then does it matter how long identifiers are? -- It's compiler generated!

Comment: @Billy: it's hard to explain all this in a few lines! What doesn't work is that if you use a typedef nested in a class, then the type name is no longer X<T>, but C<T>::X, but the name has to be X for the recursion to go through. You have to try it: that's how I know it doesn't work. I actually did try to use templates to solve the underlying problem and gave up and just generate the types plain structs. But I'm left with the problem of naming them in a way that can be shared across translation units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually need the names to agree?  Just define the structs separately, with different names, in the different translation units and `reinterpret_cast<>` where necessary to keep the C++ compiler happy. Of course that would be horrific in hand-written code, but this is code generated by your compiler, so you can (and I assume do) perform the necessary static type checks before the C++ code is generated.

If I've missed something and you really do need the type names to agree, then I think you already answered your own question: Unless the compiler can share information between the translation of multiple translation units (through some global registry), I can't see any way of generating unique, deterministic names from the type's structural form except the obvious one of name-mangling.

As for the length of names, I'm not sure why it matters? If you're considering using a hash function to shorten the names then clearly you don't need them to be human-readable, so why do they need to be short?

Personally I'd probably generate semi-human-readable names, in a similar style to existing name-mangling schemes, and not bother with the hash function. So, instead of generating `struct_int_double` you might generate `sid` (struct, int, double) or `si32f64` (struct, 32-bit integer, 64-bit float) or whatever. Names like that have the advantage that they can still be parsed directly (which seems like it would be pretty much essential for debugging).

**Edit**

Some more thoughts:

- Templates: I don't see any real advantage in generating template code to get around this problem, even if it were possible. If you're worried about hitting symbol name length limits in the linker, templates can't help you, because the linker has no concept of templates: any symbols it see will be mangled forms of the template structure generated by the C++ compiler and will have exactly the same problem as long mangled names generated directly by the felix compiler.
- Any types that have been named in felix code should be retained and used directly (or nearly directly) in the generated C++ code. I would think there are practical (soft) readability/maintainability constraints on the complexity of *anonymous* types used in felix code, which are the only ones you need to generate names for. I assume your "variants" are discriminated unions, so each component part must have a name (the tag) defined in the felix code, and again these names can be retained. (I mentioned this in a comment, but since I'm editing my answer I might as well include it)
- Reducing mangled-name length: Running a long mangled name through a hash function sounds like the easiest way to do it, and the chance of collisions should be acceptable as long as you use a good hash function and retain enough bits in your hashed name (and your alphabet for encoding the hashed name has 37 characters, so a full 160-bit sha1 hash could be written in about 31 characters). The hash function idea means that you won't be able to get directly back from a hashed name to the original name, but you might never need to do that. And you could dump out an auxiliary name-mapping table as part of the compilation process I guess (or re-generate the name from the C struct definition maybe, where it's available). Alternatively, if you still really don't like hash functions, you could probably define a reasonably compact bit-level encoding (then write that in the 37-character identifier alphabet), or even run some general purpose compression algorithm on that bit-level encoding. If you have enough felix code to analyse you could even pre-generate a fixed compression dictionary. That's stark raving bonkers of course: just use a hash.

**Edit 2:** Sorry, brain failure -- sha-1 digests are 160 bits, not 128.

---

PS. Not sure why this question was down-voted -- it seems reasonable to me, although some more context about this compiler you're working on might help.

Comment: @John: probably voted down because people don't like my tone, rather than the technical content :) If you want a pointer to the compiler: http://felix-lang.org. Generates ultra fast code (faster than C or C++ in many cases), easier to use than a scripting language and much safer.

Comment: @John: at present I "solve" this problem for function by making the programmer specify the name. For functions: export f of (int) as "f"; statement makes a C wrapper named "f" for the native function f. That's OK, but what about types needed to call f? So I make the user say export type int * double as "int_double" and this makes a typedef. External linkage here doesn't matter because extern "C" functions aren't mangled. The problem is that types can contain other types and you need to name the whole tree.. manually.

Comment: @John: length of names matters because (a) you have to debug the C++ code and hence read it and (b) because linkers have limits on name length. For simple names "sid" is fine. But Variants can often contain a 100 cases each with a tuple argument with 4 types in them, so you'd need to name 400 components which would be several thousand characters ..

Comment: But variants like that wouldn't be created anonymously, surely? For types named in felix can't you just use the felix name directly? (possibly slightly mangled to ensure uniqueness or cope with differences in identifier naming or scoping rules)

Comment: Can't see felix-lang.org at the moment (at least, the download and live links aren't working for me)

Comment: @John: sorry, yes the download and live links don't work. Do you have Linux or OSX with Git? (The project is on github, erickt/felix)

Comment: @John: You are right, anonymous variants are rare (but still need to be handled). Anonymous structs are common (tuples). Retaining type names for nominally typed types is on the cards although not currently being done. Unfortunately I also have to name functions ;( Functions in Felix are either C++ classes or ordinary functions. The former can't have the Felix name because they can be overloaded, the latter can but then you need to know type names ..

Comment: @John: live link should be up now, it might crash again (written in Felix)

Comment: @John: I have accepted your answer. Unfortunately I agree with you. You didn't actually come up with a new better idea though. No idea why the downvoters did but that's life. In fact this has been an outstanding problem in the design for a long time, it is definitely a real world compiler design problem, and its a C++ issue because I was silly enough to choose C++ as the target language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem.

```
template<typename T>
struct SListItem
{
    SListItem* m_prev;
    SListItem* m_next;
    T m_value;
};

int main()
{
    SListItem<int> sListItem;
}
```

Comment: Right, you don't understand the problem. The problem is to construct types using combinators only. You're not allowed to define any classes. You are ONLY allowed to use combinators and a fixed set of primitives. Combinators would be: tuple<>, variant<>, pointer<>, function<>.

Comment: So list is defined by: list<T> = variant< tuple<>, tuple< pointer< list<T>>>>. It can be written in Felix by "(1 + T * U) as U" where the "pointer" bit is dropped and "as U" introduces recursion without a definition: this is basically the type theorists formula, but the C++ one I gave is the same.

Comment: And yes, you can literally do that in Felix, and close to that in Ocaml and Haskell.

Comment: @Yttrill: yeah, waiting for an answer and saying "you don't understand" instead of answering clarification requests - that's the way to go. Ps. I didn't minus.

Comment: @7view: it was @nice blond stupid girl who said e didn't understand, I just confirmed it. I didn't claim that made er incompetent, contrarily, it is I who failed to explain it properly. And I did answer the clarification request.